capacitor billing plugin keeps defaulting to incorrect billing ID for in app purchase
I am using react web, ionic and capacitor to build a mobile app. I am getting a strang error with the plugin Capacitor Billing. The code here as an eample has a defualt product ID of 'fullversion' https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-billing . However even when i change the code and run in on a device i am presented with the error in xcode, inavid product id fullversion even though it is not in my code and i have synced, cleaned and rebuilt on the device. here is the code i am using which is modified from the example code given, i cant see where i am going wrong.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
IonPage,
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonContent,
  IonButtons,
  IonBackButton,
  IonIcon,
  IonList,
  IonItem,
  IonInput,
  IonLabel,
  IonItemDivider,
  } from '@ionic/react';
  import { personCircle } from 'ionicons/icons';
  import styles from '../components/lightMode.module.css';
  
  const Subscribe: React.FC = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [products, setProducts] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [Billing, setBilling] = useState<any>(null);
    
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
    const [selectedProductId, setSelectedProductId] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<string>('');
    const isDarkMode = false;
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const loadBilling = async () => {
        const BillingModule = await import('capacitor-billing');
        setBilling(BillingModule.BillingPlugin);
      };
  
      loadBilling();
        }, []);
      
        useEffect(() => {
      const fetchProducts = async () => {
        if (!Billing) return;
  
        try {
          const result = await Billing.querySkuDetails({
            productIds: ['ADSUB'], // Specify your product ID here
          });
          console.log('Query result:', result);
          
          // Handle web response for local development
          if (result.value === "web") {
            console.log('Received web response, using mock products for local development');
            setProducts([
              { id: 'ADSUB', title: 'Subscription', description: 'This is a monthly subscription service.' },
            ]);
            return;
          }

    // Ensure result is structured correctly
    if (Array.isArray(result.products)) {
      const validProducts = result.products.filter(product => product.id === 'ADSUB');
      if (validProducts.length > 0) {
        setProducts(validProducts);
      } else {
        console.error('No valid products found for ID: ADSUB');
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected result structure:', result);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
  }
};

      fetchProducts();
    }, [Billing]);
  
    // Check for password match on password change
    useEffect(() => {
      if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        setErrorMessage('Passwords do not match');
      } else {
        setErrorMessage('');
      }
    }, [password, confirmPassword]);
  
    const handlePurchase = async () => {
if (!Billing || !username || !password || password !== confirmPassword || !selectedProductId) {
  console.error('Invalid input or passwords do not match');
  return;
}

try {
  const purchase = await Billing.purchase({ productId: selectedProductId });
  console.log('Purchase successful:', purchase);
  await verifyReceipt(purchase);
  await registerUser(username, password);
} catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during purchase:', error);
      }
    };
  
    const verifyReceipt = async (purchase: any) => {
console.log('Purchase receipt:', purchase);
    };
  
    const registerUser = async (username: string, password: string) => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/restrict-content-pro/v1/subscriber', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: username.toLowerCase(),
      password: password,
    }),
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to register user');
  }

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('User registered:', data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error registering user:', error);
      }
    };

    return (
<IonPage className={styles.page}>
  <IonHeader>
    <IonToolbar>
      <IonButtons slot="start">
        <IonBackButton className={styles.backButton} defaultHref="/" />
      </IonButtons>
      <IonButtons slot="end">
        <IonIcon
          icon={personCircle}
          className={styles.settingsIcon}
          onClick={() => history.push('/Login')}
        />
      </IonButtons>
    </IonToolbar>
  </IonHeader>
  <IonContent className="ion-padding">
    <h2 style={{ paddingLeft: '15px' }}>Subscribe</h2>
    <IonItem className="no-padding">
      <IonLabel position="stacked">Enter a username (lowercase only)</IonLabel>
      <IonInput
        value={username}
        onIonChange={e => setUsername(e.detail.value!)}
        required
      />
    </IonItem>
    <IonItem className="no-padding">
      <IonLabel position="stacked">Enter a password</IonLabel>
      <IonInput
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onIonChange={e => setPassword(e.detail.value!)}
        required
      />
    </IonItem>
    <IonItem className="no-padding">
      <IonLabel position="stacked">Confirm password</IonLabel>
      <IonInput
        type="password"
        value={confirmPassword}
        onIonChange={e => setConfirmPassword(e.detail.value!)}
        required
      />
    </IonItem>
    {errorMessage && (
      <h6 className={styles.errorMessage}>
        {errorMessage}
      </h6>
    )}
    <IonItemDivider />
    <IonList>
      {products.length > 0 ? (
        products.map(product => (
          <IonItem key={product.id} className="no-padding" onClick={() => setSelectedProductId(product.id)}>
            <h3>{product.title}</h3>
            <p>{product.description}</p>
          </IonItem>
        ))
      ) : (
        <IonItem className="no-padding">
          <p className={styles.grey}>Loading products...</p>
        </IonItem>
      )}
    </IonList>
    <div
      className={isDarkMode ? styles.darkModeMore2 : styles.lightModeMore2}
      onClick={handlePurchase}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#33abae',
        color: '#fff',
        padding: '12px',
        textAlign: 'center',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        borderRadius: '4px',
        marginTop: '16px',
      }}
    >
      Subscribe
    </div>
  </IonContent>
</IonPage>
    );
  };
  
  export default Subscribe;

